# react-native-webview use androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.0 to get rid of x-requested-with header

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I am using the `react-native-webview` in my React Native app and struggling to get rid of the `x-requested-with` header which is automatically added to every network request on Android webview.

There are multiple solutions on StackOverflow that describe how to delete that header but they are old and do not work for me.

According to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226552535#comment9 if you upgrade Webkit to v1.6.0-alpha02 this header should not be added at all.

I tried adding `implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.0-alpha02"` in my project's dependencies list in`android/app/build.gradle` file and also in `node_modules/react-native-webview/android/build.gradle'.

Result:
App builds fine but the header is still automatically added there as well.

Could you please help to find what is wrong in what I am doing?

Thank you